# Rereating the blocks content in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Ie7 repeats the blocks content if i write `float: left;` to that block. Has anyone the same problem? How could I fix that? Any ideas?

Comment: Not so easy =\ private project.

Comment: Then remove all the extra chrome and create a simplified example - actually in doing this you may discover what the problem is yourself. IF not you have something to show us so we have more to go on. you might also check these: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

Answer (score 0):

Graphical glitches like repeated content are usually caused by a lack of layout.

Try adding `zoom:1;` to the styles for the element in question. If it's fixed, then you know the issue is a missing layout.